# Workbook.Open VBA Syntax Error expecting "="

Tags: excel, vba

The following code shows a syntax error. A compile error expecting an "=". Can't understand what the error is. Please help.

Creating a macro to open multiple password protected workbooks.

```
    Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile & myExtension, Password:=pw)
```

A compile error expecting an "=". Can't understand what the error is. Please help.

Comment: Remove the brackets `Workbooks.Open Filename:=myPath & myFile  & myExtension, Password:=pw`

Comment: You freaking Rock! Ty!

Comment: You have to use `()` when you are setting it to a Variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we can mark this as answered (Chris Neilsen):

By adjusting the code from:
`Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile & myExtension, Password:=pw)` to `Workbooks.Open Filename:=myPath & myFile & myExtension, Password:=pw`

The code runs fine now